# when sharing a page on facebook using addthis, image aren't shown

Tags: facebook, share

when sharing a page on facebook using addthis, image aren't shown on the facebook.

the sharing link on facebook [shown as this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l77Ya.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can define an image using Open Graph Meta Tags in your HTML code. Facebook will then use this image as preview for your post.
You can read more about Open Graph at their website: http://ogp.me

Use the tag "og:image" to properly link your image:

```
<head>
...
<meta property="og:title" content="Title of webpage"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="A description of your page"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="previewimage.png" />
...
</head>
```

Comment: here is html example I am using. 
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="<%= title %>" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="<%= description %>" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="<%= img_url %>" />

Comment: Did you substitute <%= img_url %> to your relative image path? For example changing <%= img_url %> to <"images/previewbanner.png">.

Comment: No .I am using an absolute image url but the image adress containts some unicode characters so I am using html encode method to get the write image url

Comment: but when i use an image from the other web sites image shown correctly.I thing  the problem is related to publishing server